# Can I claim UI benefits in NY if I moved few months ago?

Tags: united-states, new-york, unemployment

I started working in NY state in December '13, and for various reasons I'm currently unemployed. Can I still claim unemployment benefits, or 4 months are not enough for it?

Comment: You have a many unknowns in your question but here is a place to start: https://www.labor.ny.gov/ui/claimantinfo/beforeyouapplyfaq.shtm#0

Comment: Apply. Answer the questions truthfully. The worst they can say is no.

Comment: What did you do before December 2013? The time worked and the money earned in a previous state may also apply to your qualification situation. If you collected unemployment for that previous period that may also factor into your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [Claimant Handbook](https://www.labor.ny.gov/formsdocs/ui/TC318.3e.pdf), pp 6-7, for New York Unemployment Insurance:

> To qualify for benefits,   you must    meet    all three   of  the following   requirements:
>
> - You  must    have    worked  and been    paid    wages   for covered employment  in  at 
>     least two calendar quarters in  your    Basic   or  Alternate   Base    Period.
> - You  must    have    been    paid    at  least   $1,700  in  wages   in  one of  the calendar    quarters
>     in  your    base    period. Effective   January 1,  2015,   you must    have    been    paid    at  least
>     $1,900  in  wages   in  one of  the calendar    quarters    in  your    base    period.
> - The total   wages   paid    to  you in  your    Basic   or  Alternate   Base    Period  must    be  at 
>     least one and one-half times your high quarter wages.   Your    high    quarter 
>     wages   are the wages   paid    in  the calendar    quarter in  which   you were    paid    the 
>     most money. Exceptions: If  your    high    quarter wages   equal   $8,910  or  more,   your    wages   in  the other   base    period  quarters    must    total   at  least   one-half    of  $8,910, or  $4,455. Effective   the first   Monday  of  October 2014,   if  your    high    quarter wages   equal   $9,240  or  more,   your    wages   in  the other   base    period  quarters    must    total   at  least   one-half    of  $9,240, or  $4,620.

[Available in [multiple languages](https://www.labor.ny.gov/ui/claimantinfo/Claimant%20Handbook%20-%20Languages.shtm).]

If you worked four months, then you worked in at least two quarters.  The Basic Base Period is the first four quarters of the five-quarter period immediately prior to your claim.  If your claim begins this quarter, then that means the period Jan-Dec 2013, so you won't have 2 worked quarters.  But under the Alternate Base Period, the last four quarters before the quarter your claim begins, you have Q1 '14 and Q4 '13.  So you have the two worked quarters.

You must have made at least $1,700 in a quarter.  And you must have made no more than 2/3 your wages from your highest paid quarter.  This latter rule may be tough for you if you were employed Dec to Apr, so you may be in a situation where 3/4 or more of your income from the Alternate Base Period came from first quarter of 2014.  The $8,910 rule does not help you out, even if you made that much in January through March, because you only have two worked quarters.

Work out the details based on your situation.  I suspect that you will not qualify because of the income distribution rule #3.